# How to return specific document from different collection by a specific field inside aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to populate just those documents from `users` collection where `users._id` is equal to `levelOne.assignedPeople` ids. This will arrive as an array.

I am using this query,

```
db.parentepics.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
      ideaId: "616bffd81a9c715679374b19",
      isDeleted: false,
      isHidden: false,
      isRemovedByOwner: false,
    },
},
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "childtasklevelones",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "parentEpicId",
      as: "level_1",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "level_1.assignedPeople": ObjectId('616c00001a9c715679374b1b'),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      epicName: 1,
      epicDescription: 1,
      epicPriority: 1,
      startsFrom: 1,
      endsAt: 1,
      levelOne: "$level_1",
    },
  }
])
```

Which produces some output looks like this,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("616c099e1a9c715679374b7c"),
    "epicName" : "Marketing",
    "epicDescription" : "Marketing data",
    "epicPriority" : "1",
    "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-15T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
    "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-30T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
    "levelOne" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("616db350123f016231912954"),
            "currentStatus" : "pending",
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("616c00001a9c715679374b1b")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "yellow",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "Marketing",
            "taskDescription" : "Marketing data",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-15T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-30T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("616bffd81a9c715679374b18"),
            "parentEpicId" : ObjectId("616c099e1a9c715679374b7c"),
            "taskNameToLower" : "marketing",
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-18T23:18:00.464+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-18T23:18:00.464+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I just need to populate users from users collection where `users._id` is equal to `levelOne.assignedPeople`.

I sort, I need the array of users in place of these `levelOne.assignedPeople` ids.

Please help me to modify the query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an extra `lookup` stage. In this case, because `level_1.assignedPeople` is already an array, we can just use the `lookup` stage to replace the array of User Object IDs with an array of User Objects.

Example:

```
db.parentepics.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        ideaId: "616bffd81a9c715679374b19",
        isDeleted: false,
        isHidden: false,
        isRemovedByOwner: false,
    } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "childtasklevelones",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "parentEpicId",
        as: "level_1",
    } },
    { $match: {
        "level_1.assignedPeople": ObjectId('616c00001a9c715679374b1b'),
    } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "level_1.assignedPeople",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "level_1.assignedPeople",
    } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        epicName: 1,
        epicDescription: 1,
        epicPriority: 1,
        startsFrom: 1,
        endsAt: 1,
        levelOne: "$level_1",
    } }
])
```

Comment: now it is returning me the assigned people object, not replacing the ids.